# How can I have sidebar widgets on Twenty Seventeen theme on all pages?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-twenty-seventeen

How can I have sidebar widgets on Twenty Seventeen theme on all pages? Right now it's possible only on Blog page, not on any other page.

Thanks for any help,
Afan

Comment: unfortunately, third party theme questions are off-topic here. however, there is a plugin available https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-sidebar-for-twentyseventeen/ or you can ask in https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentyseventeen

Comment: Oh? I thought, since "Twenty Seventeen is the official WordPress theme in 2017..." it shouldn't be a problem.
Thanks for the links, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried "Page Sidebar for Twenty Seventeen" plugin. Didn't spend a lot of time but looks like it works fine.

Thanks a lot for the link, I appreciate it.
Afan

P.S. In case this is not allowed to post, feel free to remove this post.